# How to create a Pie Chart Using Polygon in css

Tags: html, css, polygon, pie-chart

I want to create a pie chart using css polygons but not fulfill my goal my chart is looking like this.

The chart that i create is not matching with the desired chart may but i am not matching the angles properly.

[image]

Here are my codes:

```css
.pie{
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
        
.circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
        
.animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(.74,1.13,.83,1.2);
  -moz-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(.74,1.13,.83,1.2);
  -o-transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(.74,1.13,.83,1.2);
  transition: 0.2s cubic-bezier(.74,1.13,.83,1.2);
}
        
.animate:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transform-origin: center center;
}
    
#part1 {
  background-color: #E64C65;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 50% 50%, 100% 41.2%, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 50% 50%, 100% 65.7%, 100% 0);
}
    
    #part2 {
  background-color: #11A8AB;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 41.2%, 100% 100%, 63.4% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 41.2%, 100% 100%, 63.4% 100%);
}

#part3 {
  background-color: #4FC4F6;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 36.6% 100%, 63.4% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 36.6% 100%, 63.4% 100%);
}

#part4 {
  background-color: #FFED0D;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 100%, 36.6% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 100%, 36.6% 100%);
}

#part5 {
  background-color: #F46FDA;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 36.6%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 36.6%, 0 100%);
}

#part6 {
  background-color: #15BFCC;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 36.6%, 0 0, 50% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0 36.6%, 0 0, 50% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="pie">
  <div id="part1" class="circle animate"></div>
 <div id="part2" class="circle animate"></div>
 <div id="part3" class="circle animate"></div>
 <div id="part4" class="circle animate"></div>
 <div id="part5" class="circle animate"></div>
 <div id="part6" class="circle animate"></div>
</div>
```

I am going to make the chart like in the image but don't fulfill my goal.
will you please help me to make the chart like this.